# What is the idle ramp up period for the 1000 users in the JMeter, while working on SharePoint online app?

Tags: jmeter-5.0

While working on the SharePoint app, I noticed that it takes more than 10 seconds to load the app first time. so, I was thinking that how much ramp-up period will be idle for running 1000 users on JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "idle", do you mean "ideal" ramp-up?

I believe the slow initial load can be explained by how IIS internally works:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/297fb51b-b7b4-4b7b-a898-f6c91efd994e/sharepoint-2013-first-load-takes-long-time?forum=sharepointadmin

Taking all that the information into account, we can predict that high response times due to the long initial load will occur for at most several minutes in the beginning of your test and affect the users which are started during this period.

Finding out the "ideal" ramp-up time can be a little bit tricky.

I would address the problem like that:

Add the Response Times Over Time (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/) graph.
Set the ramp-up time to 10 seconds per user and, using the graph added above, find out when the response times will settle down. This will mean that the initial load of the application is completed. Don't forget to exclude this period from the report.

Now you should observe that the response times are slowly growing with the addition of new users.

After the addition of all of the users, if everything went well, you can try to lower your ramp-up time to, say, 3600 seconds for all of the users.
If you see that the response times skyrocketed and/or exceeded the SLA, than you either are adding the users too fast, or the application is already saturated.